# Passing an instance of a class as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, class, exception

So, I need to pass an instance of Labyrinth class from Form1 class to Player class when a key is pressed so that the Player would be able to move through the labyrinth where there's no collision. 
   First I declare a Labyrinth object globally so that when created in OnMouseClick function it will be available everywhere in the class and then in OnKeyPress function I pass it to an instance of Player class and perform movement with Move function and check collision.
   I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception and I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Maybe I messed up somewhere in declaring or instantiating labyrinth class, but I simply don't know the other way to do it. Any suggestions?

```
namespace Labyrinth
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Player player = new Player();
        Labyrinth labyrinth;

        private void OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (window=="lvlSelect")
                string clicked = levelMenu.Click(e);

            switch (clicked)
            {
                case "1":
                  level = 1; 
                  Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth(level);
                  break;
                case "2":
                  level = 2; 
                  Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth(level);
                  break;
                case "3":
                  level = 3; 
                  Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth(level);
                  break;
            }           
        }

        private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char key = e.KeyChar;
            if (window == "game")
            {player.Move(k = key.ToString(), labyrinth)}
        }
    }
}

namespace Labyrinth
{
    class Player
    {
        int playerPosX;
        int playerPosY;
        public void Move(string key, Labyrinth labyrinth)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "a":
                    if (!(playerPosX - 1 < 0) && 
                        (labyrinth.CheckCollision(playerPosX - 1, playerPosY)==false)) //I get the exception here
                        playerPosX--;
                    break;
                case ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth(level);` should just be `labyrinth = new Labyrinth(level);`.

Comment: Your problem is probably because `clicked` is not equal to `1`, `2` or `3`, which is causing `labyrinth` not to be initialized. Try adding a `default` to your `switch` statement. Also, you can completely elliminate the `switch` statement all together by simply writing `Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth(int.Parse(clicked));`

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
It should be initialised as it works perfectly if I initialise Labyrinth in OnKeyPress function and Move function separately, so switch works as it's expected. I tried to declare Labyrinth globally and pass it to avoid some problems.

Comment: maybe you try 
player.Move(k = key.ToString(), this)

Comment: It doesn't work that way as the class I pass it from is Form1, I need to pass an instance of Labyrinth, not Form1

Comment: Labyrinth labyrinth;  because of this you never define a new instance.
Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth();
Labyrinth labyrinth without assign anything by default the object will be null with Labyrinth 's "structure" sorry. your click inside is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Player player = new Player();
        Labyrinth labyrinth = new Labyrinth(1); // you need to default it to 1 first instead of null. because you might key press then only mouse click

        private void OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
         string clicked = "1"; /// default clicked to 1
            if (window=="lvlSelect") /// if selected level is diff, then change
                 clicked = levelMenu.Click(e);
        labyrinth = new Labyrinth(Convert.ToInt(level)); 
        }

        private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char key = e.KeyChar;
            if (window == "game")
            {player.Move(k = key.ToString(), labyrinth)}
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can remove switch (clicked) instead.    just change 15lines to one line.
labyrinth = new Labyrinth(convert.toint( clicked));

Comment: If I remove it from case, how do I declare it with parameter "level" outside the function?

Comment: my bad. you code should have error while comppile. let me change on the existing code

Comment: i have updated the code, capital/small letter or spelling might have error. please i don have vs with me for the moment.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try it out and tell you if it works.

Comment: It helped. Thank you so much for your answer!  
Because I kept declaring new private instances of Labyrinth, the global instance had been kept unchanged. How stupid of me. The way you did it worked perfectily.